# How do I pgrep by the first command line argument?

Tags: linux, grep, process

I want to use `pgrep` to [find the pid of a process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18765298/925913), *e.g.*

```
$ pgrep bluetoothd
441
```

However, the processes I need to search run within a wrapper called `RunFIDProcess`:

```
[cama@dc1-dev-lin-1204 tests]$ ps -ef | grep RunFIDProcess
tps        544     1  0 Dec13 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh .//RunFIDProcess CASE_SJDI SJdi -c SJdi.auto.cfg -m PRIMARY_WARM
tps        546     1  0 Dec13 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh .//RunFIDProcess CASE_ETH Eth -c Eth.cfg
tps        547     1  0 Dec13 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh .//RunFIDProcess CASE_DBWEBSERVER DbWebServer
tps        556     1  0 Dec13 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh .//RunFIDProcess CASE_TABLE_PROXY TableProxy -c TableProxy.cfg
cama      4519     1  0 07:30 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh .//RunFIDProcess CASE_SJDI SJdi -c SJdi.auto.cfg -m PRIMARY_WARM
cama      4524     1  0 07:30 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh .//RunFIDProcess CAMA_DS5_QRY DaqSvr -m cold -c cama_DaqSvr.DS5.cfg
cama      4530     1  0 07:30 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh .//RunFIDProcess CAMA_US_OSUB Osub -c cama_Osub.US.auto.cfg -Cold
cama      4534     1  0 07:30 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh .//RunFIDProcess CAMA_DS7_QRY DaqSvr -m cold -c cama_DaqSvr.DS7.cfg
```

So,

```
[cama@dc1-dev-lin-1204 tests]$ pgrep CAMA_US_OSUB
```

returns nothing.

How can I find a process by its name as well as its first command line argument?

Comment: `pgrep -f CAMA_US_0SUB`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-f` switch to `pgrep` allows it to search the full list of arguments to each process.  You can therefore use `pgrep -f CAMA_US_0SUB` to search for anything with that used at its argument (or indeed processes with that name).